# "CMakeCUDACompilerId.cu" failed что делать?

Tags: c++, cmake, pytorch, cuda

устанавливал дистрибутивы pytorch через cmake
cmake

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18 FATAL_ERROR)
project(example-app)

find_package(Torch REQUIRED)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${TORCH_CXX_FLAGS}")

add_executable(example-app example-app.cpp)
target_link_libraries(example-app "${TORCH_LIBRARIES}")
set_property(TARGET example-app PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 17)

# The following code block is suggested to be used on Windows.
# According to https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/25457,
# the DLLs need to be copied to avoid memory errors.
if (MSVC)
  file(GLOB TORCH_DLLS "${TORCH_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib/*.dll")
  add_custom_command(TARGET example-app
                     POST_BUILD
                     COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different
                     ${TORCH_DLLS}
                     $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:example-app>)
endif (MSVC)
```

вывод в командной строке:

```
PS C:\example-app> cd build
PS C:\example-app\build> cmake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=C:\libtorch ..
-- Building for: Visual Studio 17 2022
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.22000.0 to target Windows 10.0.22621.
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.37.32825.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.37.32825.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.37.32822/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.37.32822/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found CUDA: C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v11.8 (found version "11.8") 
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.28/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:780 (message):
  Compiling the CUDA compiler identification source file
  "CMakeCUDACompilerId.cu" failed.

  Compiler:

  Build flags:

  Id flags: --keep;--keep-dir;tmp -v



  The output was:

  1

  Версия MSBuild 17.7.2+d6990bcfa для .NET Framework

  Сборка начата 06.11.2023 10:47:38.



  Проект
  "C:\example-app\build\CMakeFiles\3.28.0-rc2\CompilerIdCUDA\CompilerIdCUDA.vcxproj"
  в узле 1 (целевые объекты по умолчанию).

  PrepareForBuild:

    Создание каталога "Debug\".
    Создание каталога "Debug\CompilerIdCUDA.tlog\".

  InitializeBuildStatus:

    Создание "Debug\CompilerIdCUDA.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild", так как было задано "AlwaysCreate".
    Обращение к "Debug\CompilerIdCUDA.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild".

  AddCudaCompileDeps:

    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\bin\HostX64\x64\cl.exe /E /nologo /showIncludes /TP /D__CUDACC__ /D__CUDACC_VER_MAJOR__=12 /D__CUDACC_VER_MINOR__=3 /D_MBCS /Iinclude /Ibin /Iinclude /I. /FIcuda_runtime.h /c C:\example-app\build\CMakeFiles\3.28.0-rc2\CompilerIdCUDA\CMakeCUDACompilerId.cu

  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual
  Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\BuildCustomizations\CUDA
  12.3.targets(606,9): error : The CUDA Toolkit v12.3 directory '' does not
  exist.  Please verify the CUDA Toolkit is installed properly or define the
  CudaToolkitDir property to resolve this error.
  [C:\example-app\build\CMakeFiles\3.28.0-rc2\CompilerIdCUDA\CompilerIdCUDA.vcxproj]


  Сборка проекта
  "C:\example-app\build\CMakeFiles\3.28.0-rc2\CompilerIdCUDA\CompilerIdCUDA.vcxproj"
  завершена (целевые объекты по умолчанию)
  с ошибкой.



  Ошибка сборки.




  "C:\example-app\build\CMakeFiles\3.28.0-rc2\CompilerIdCUDA\CompilerIdCUDA.vcxproj"
  (целевой объект по умолчанию) (1) ->

  (Целевой объект ValidateCudaBuild) ->

    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\BuildCustomizations\CUDA 12.3.targets(606,9): error : The CUDA Toolkit v12.3 directory '' does not exist.  Please verify the CUDA Toolkit is installed properly or define the CudaToolkitDir property to resolve this error. [C:\example-app\build\CMakeFiles\3.28.0-rc2\CompilerIdCUDA\CompilerIdCUDA.vcxproj]



      Предупреждений: 0
      Ошибок: 1



  Прошло времени 00:00:00.35





Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.28/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:8 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID_BUILD)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.28/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:53 (__determine_compiler_id_test)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.28/Modules/CMakeDetermineCUDACompiler.cmake:135 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID)
  C:/libtorch/share/cmake/Caffe2/public/cuda.cmake:47 (enable_language)
  C:/libtorch/share/cmake/Caffe2/Caffe2Config.cmake:87 (include)
  C:/libtorch/share/cmake/Torch/TorchConfig.cmake:68 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:4 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
PS C:\example-app\build>
```

Помогите разобраться с этой проблемой, действовал строго согласно туториалу по установке на сайте https://pytorch.org/cppdocs/installing.html#
Установлена cuda toolkit v11.8 с официального сайта cuda , в переменных среды path путь к cuda указан